# Facebook API: Get gender of event attenders

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i've found this page where they display events in your local town (based on Facebook events):

http://www.wherevent.com/detail/Kastellaun-Burgstadt-und-Weihnachtsmarkt-in-der-Burgstadt

As you can see they also show the attenders on the left side grouped by the gender.

Ok let's say you know the eventid and so you can get the names and userids of the attenders by this way:

https://graph.facebook.com/[eventid]/attending

But how do they get the gender/sex of each attender?!?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. They would need to login to your app and grant you permission to it

Comment: Seeing as in several instances it shows me profile pictures that show _couples_ inside both the female _and_ the male slider, I'd assume they use some kind of facial rec to guess the gender, and "err on the side of caution" by counting couple's photos as both. (Granted, could be couples where both are individual user accounts that have the same profile pic set. Chances for seeing that several times right away? Small, I'd say.)